# Run jQuery function 5 times after resize

Tags: jquery, function, flexslider, window-resize

Is it possible to run a function only 5 times after resize the window? When you resize again, run the function again 5 times.

```
$(window).bind('resize', function() { 
    setTimeout(function(){ 
        var slider = $('.wrapper .flexslider').data('flexslider');   
        slider.resize();
    }, 500);
});
```

This function is running every 0.5 sec. but the browser can't handle it and running this function once is not enough to resize flexslider properly (I don't know why).

Comment: It's running many more times than you think. `resize` handler doesn't just run once. During manual resize you will be applying 100's of `setTimeout`

Comment: Is there an alternative?

Comment: I think the real thing that is suspicious is that you need to call `resize()` more than once. It might be worth investigating why you need to do that.

Comment: Read up on how to `throttle` or `debounce` a resize handler. Need to clear all the `setTimeout`'s you are unknowingly creating

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Add a callback to your function, and call it again, recursively, as many times as needed.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of the debounce function as mentioned in the comments.

```
function debounce(func, wait, immediate) {
        var timeout;
        return function() {
            var context = this, args = arguments;
            var later = function() {
                timeout = null;
                if (!immediate) func.apply(context, args);
            };
            var callNow = immediate && !timeout;
            clearTimeout(timeout);
            timeout = setTimeout(later, wait);
            if (callNow) func.apply(context, args);
        };
    };

    var myEfficientFn = debounce( function() {
       // Your resize code here, only fired once
    }, 500);

    window.addEventListener('resize', myEfficientFn);
```